# Shell script - Bad substitution Error while running script with sh

Tags: shell, sh

I am trying to loop inside a directory and rename the file name with space. But i m getting the bad substitution error while running it with sh test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in /home/admin1/abc/*.kmz
do
mv "$f" "${f// /_}"
#rm $i
done
```

Since i need to configure in crontab i may need to run it with sh command not with ./

Comment: Your sh may not be bash. Try `bash test.sh`.

Comment: Glad I could help. Made my comment an answer you can accept :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make my comment an answer:

You're running with `sh`, but your script declares it's a `bash` script. On many systems `sh` is not `bash`, but a lighter shell that doesn't support all bashisms.

Either

- run with `bash test.sh`, or
- mark the file `chmod u+x` and run `./test.sh` to use the shebang line.

Answer (score 1):

Bourne Shell `sh` doesn't support this type of substitution. You could run this script:

```
for f in /home/admin1/abc/*.kmz
do
  mv "$f" `echo "$f" |tr ' ' _`
done
```